# Ansible как работать со списком объектов

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

имеется playbook ansible. Хотелось бы его модифицировать под свои нужды. Проблема заключается в следующем. Я хочу задавать собственные поля в системе на основе данных playbook. Туда я вношу данные следующим образом

```
- name: dicts
  hosts: all
 
  list_items: 
    - {item1: "aaa", item2: "bbb"}
    - {item1: "ccc", item2: "ddd"}
  
  tasks:
    - name: Start Program
      command: "./my_app.py {{ item.item1 }} {{ item.item2 }}"
      with_items: {{ list_items }}
```

В таком виде Playbook ругается на задание списка list_items. Ошибка Did not find expected indicator "-".
Вроде бы по логике этот дефис там не нужен. Как можно исправить подобный playbook для корректного чтения?

UPD.
Также встречается ошибка другого рода:

```
with_items:
  - {{ foo }}
Should be written as 
with_items:
  - "{{ foo }}"
```

Такое исправление возвращает меня назад к первой ошибке

Upd: Вопрос к комментарию - сработает ли такая конфигурация?

```
- name: dicts
  hosts: all

  vars:
    list_items:
      - { item1: aaa, item2: bbb }
      - { item1: ccc, item2: ddd }

  tasks:

    - name: Start Program
      command: "./my_app.py {{ item.item1 }} {{ item.item2 }}"
      with_items: "{{ list_items }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ты забыл кавычки в `with_items`. Надо, чтобы было так: `with_items: "{{ list_items }}"`.

Плюс ты не рассказал Ансиблу, что `list_items` - это переменная. Нужно записать это в `vars:`.

Исправленный плейбук выглядит так:

```yaml
- name: dicts
  hosts: all

  vars:
    list_items:
      - item1: aaa
        item2: bbb
      - item1: ccc
        item2: ddd

  tasks:

    - name: Start Program
      command: "./my_app.py {{ item.item1 }} {{ item.item2 }}"
      with_items: "{{ list_items }}"
```

Comment: А перечисление в фигурных скобках вместо последовательного по полям item1-2 в vars возможно?

Comment: Не совсем понял что ты имеешь ввиду. Можно уточнить? Лучше в виде редактирования вопроса и добавления в конец того чё ты ща спрашиваешь.

Comment: Я добавил данные к вопросу. У меня идет много данных в формате JSON, хотелось бы не терять формат, за исключением конфигурации

Comment: Блин. Ты только vars исправил и не проверил тупым запуском? Я думал, что чё-то прям сильно сложное, что я не понял. Почитай на Википедии что такое YAML и как он "дружит" с JSON. А ещё https://json2yaml.com/ в закладки добавь и присмотрись к проекту `yq`.

Comment: @arrr, ну чё, если ответ верный - отметь галкой.